# TOR IP confustion Luxembourg or Kentucky or Arizona?

Tags: ip, ip2location

I tried my web site with TOR.

I the IP I got was `104.244.73.13`

`whatismyipaddress.com` says this IP coming from Lebanon from Kentucky United States.

It also calls it "Hostname: **luxembourg**torexit1".

`www.ip2location.com` says that this IP coming from Bissen from Mersch **Luxembourg**.

It also knows that it is "Proxy Type    (TOR) Tor Exit Node"

It gets even more interesting with `www.whatismyip.com`. It gives 2 options

one from `IP2Location.com` and it is `Luxembourg`

and the other one from `ipdata.co` and it is Phoenix Arizona!

I honestly never seen such conflicts between IP tracking services.

Who gives the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

It should be in Luxembourg.

If you use ping.pe and test ping latency to 104.244.73.13 from different locations. The server in Europe has the lowest latency to prove that it is nearby.